# AngularJS automapper for result from restful service

Tags: angularjs, rest, typescript

I use $resource service for data access from restful service. Result of $resource("path") I put in typescript domain object. Problem is that I get json in form like this:

```
{
    "name_surname": "john_smith",
    "years_of_employment": "10"
}
```

and I want to map it to domain object of this class:

```
class Employee {
    constructor(public FullName: string, public YearsOfEmployment: number) { }
}
```

So there is mismatch between names of properties inside domain class and json fields. Is there any angularjs module I can use for mapping between those two, and what is the most elegant way to accomplish that?

Answer (score 0):

I am using this in one of my projects.
It maps my shortened properties to readable properties for development.
Maybe this snippet can help you.

```
(function (angular) {
    "use strict";

    angular.module("services.mapper", []).service("mapper", [function ()      {
        var models = {
            employeeModelContract: {
                name_surname: "FullName",
                years_of_employment: "YearsOfEmployment"
            } 
        };

        return {
            map: map,
            models: models
        }

        function map(smallObject, contract) {
            var largeObject = {};
            for (var smallProperty in contract) {
                if (contract.hasOwnProperty(smallProperty)) {
                    largeObject[contract[smallProperty]] = smallObject[smallProperty];
                }
            }
            return largeObject;
        }
    }]);
})(angular);
```

Usage:

```
var mappedObject = mapper.map(yourJson, mapper.models.employeeModelContract);
```

UPDATE 1 (Typescript version):

```
class MapperService implements ng.IServiceProvider {

    employeeModelContract:Object= {
        name_surname: "FullName",
        years_of_employment: "YearsOfEmployment"
    };

    $get() { 
        return this;
    }

    map(smallObject, contract): Object {
        var mappedObject: Object = {};
        Object.keys(contract).forEach(contractProperty => {
            if (contract.hasOwnProperty(contractProperty)) {
                mappedObject[contract[contractProperty]] = smallObject[contractProperty];
            }
        });
        return mappedObject; 
    }
}

class Employee {
    constructor(public FullName: string, public YearsOfEmployment: number) { }
}

class Controller implements ng.IController {

    constructor(private mapper : MapperService){}

    static $inject = ["MapperService"];

    json: Object = {
        "name_surname": "john_smith",
        "years_of_employment": "10"
    }

    $onInit(): void {
        var mapped = <Employee>this.mapper.map(this.json, this.mapper.employeeModelContract);
    }
}

angular.module("mapper", []).controller("Controller",Controller).provider("MapperService", MapperService);
```

Comment: Since I use typescript, I am looking for typescript mapper, not pure javascript.